# "Middleman" for URLs (http opens)

Tags: windows, http

I was wondering if there is a possibility to have a middleman/firewall-like functionality in Windows which would enable me to review the URL the application is trying to send to the browser and decide if I want to pass if through or not?

Example: skype->url in chat->allow->opens in browser

Example: installer->random url containing "anonymous pc data" + ip->deny

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing. If a URL is obfuscated, you may be able to copy it to the clip board and paste it to a text document to see what it contains, but I know of no tool that will automate such a process. If, however, it is obfuscation through a shortening service (e.g., bit.ly), there is at least [one](http://unshort.me/http://unshort.me/) unshortening service that may be of use.

Comment: no, applications in windows can auto-open urls in the default browser. this circumvents them from being blocked by a rule-based firewall.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question.

Comment: Well, a default app that would "take" http links (then decide to drop or allow) would solve this..

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in programming at all this would be a very simple and very good "first real project"

Simply write a program that takes an argument, displays it with a confirm our deny box, then launches your browser with the URL if you select confirm and exits if deny.

Then set it as your default browser.

I'm unaware of any program that already exists being available.

Comment: This would not intercept any links from programs that hard code a browser (e.g., those that forcibly open links in IE).

Comment: You are correct. At the end of the day sandboxing a Turing complete application is an extremely hard problem. The best answer is if you don't trust the program don't run it.

Comment: Usually apps just sent the http link to the default browser, I was wondering if such a filter (app junk detected, divert to browser?) already exists...